# Laravel Scout: Only update when specific fields change

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm trying to optimise my application by only updating my Algolia records (and therefore saving on thousands of unnecessary operations) when data that I care about changes.

I have a table that holds price information about various products that is updated every minute when the price changes. Currently, the searchable model in Algolia is kept in sync with this as intended but this is unnecessary as the search function on my site only provides search for the products themselves, not the prices.

Currently, Scout performs an operation in Algolia every time the `update()` method is called on the model (once every minute on *each* model).

**Is there a way that I could conditionally trigger Algolia to update only when the manufacturer, product, or variant of the model changes and not the price?**

The `toSearchableArray()` function on my model currently looks like this, if that helps at all:

```php
public function toSearchableArray() {

            return [
                'id'                    => $this->id,
                'manufacturer'          => $this->manufacturer,
                'product'               => $this->product,
                'variant'               => $this->variant,
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `withoutSyncingToSearch` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scout#pausing-indexing) what you are looking for?

This would mean wrapping wherever you currently update your prices in this method.

Whilst this code is not provided in your question, I assume something along the lines of:

```
\App\Model::withoutSyncingToSearch ( function() use ($item, $newPrice) {
    $item->price = $newPrice;
    $item->save();
});
```

could work for you?

Comment: Fantastic, this looks like the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add following function to your model:

```
public function searchIndexShouldBeUpdated()
{
    if (empty(array_intersect_key( $this->getChanges(),$this->toSearchableArray() )))
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It will check if last update had changed any properties in your searchable array and will only update search index if such updates were made.

Comment: I would rather use something like: $this->isDirty(['subject','body','slug',]);